# Data extract security in Tableau

Tags: data-extraction, tableau-api

I am trying to put the security on the data extract which is published to the Tableau server via embedded works or published as independent extract which can consumed by other users. Below are the scenarios:

Scenario#1
There are two users User1 and User2
User1 has access to Impala however don't have access to some tables let's say "employee" table.
User2 has access to Impala also  "employee" table. User2 created the data extract out of employee table and used in the workbook.
Later on workbook is published on Tableau server which is accessible by user1. Now user1 can view the data of employee table however data is restricted to User1 at table level.How we can imposed the security at extract level to prevent the security breach.

Scenario#2
I have created the extract out of Impala table which is published on the Tableau server and scheduled it periodically.
When the data is extracted from the impala tables periodically which account has been used to extract the data from impala?
Is it the service account on which Tableau service running is used or user account who published the data source on Tableau server is used?
How the impala identify which accounts needs to be used?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Set permissions on the data source, or the workbook](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#permissions.htm)
2. If [credentials have been embedded](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/embedding-database-credentials-tableau-server?lang=en-us) when the extract was published, then those credentials will be used. Otherwise, the Tableau Server Run As user account will be used

Comment: Regarding #1:If you give someone privileges to connect to a data source extract, and they can create a tableau workbook, then they can make a worksheet to view everything in the extract. If you want to enforce a user filter on an extract (instead of a live source), at a minimum, I'd expect you would want to keep the extract packaged within the workbook that enforces the user filter. (and consider other attack vectors also). For example, restrict the ability to download the workbook since the extract will come with it.